# Flutter text to speech not working on real device

Tags: flutter, text-to-speech

I was making an app in flutter which used the flutter_tts package. The flutter text to speech worked perfectly on the emulator, but when I built the app on a real device, it does not function.

```
speak(String text) async {
      await flutterTts.setLanguage('ro');
      await flutterTts.setPitch(1.0);
      await flutterTts.speak(text);
    }
```

This is the code snippet that enables the talk function.

Can someone help me identify the issue please?

P.S. I am kind of a noob to stackoverflow so I don't really know if I should add any extra stuff, so tell me if you need anything.

I tried searching up the problem on the internet with 0 succes, and some help on at least what coul be the problem would be apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I found the issue,

You have to set the system language to whatever language you have on your text to speech. Got really scared there :).

Answer (score 0):

Before setting the language check if the language is available on the device using the `isLanguageAvailable()` method

```
try {
  var language = 'ro';
  var isLanguageAvailable = await flutterTts.isLanguageAvailable(language);

  if (isLanguageAvailable) {
    await flutterTts.setLanguage(language);
    await flutterTts.setPitch(1.0);
    await flutterTts.speak(text);
  } else {
    print('Language $language is not available on this device.');
  }
} catch (ex) {
  print('Unexpected error: $ex');
}
```

If you go to your "Settings" and then search for "Text-to-speech output" you can see your available languages.